Python to sort nested XML alongside unsorted siblings
I need to sort the "line" elements of the following sample XML with Elementtree by reqdate (desc - most recent to oldest).
<doc>
    <header>
        <ordernum>1234</ordernum>
        <customer>1</customer>
        <line>
            <lineno>1</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-01-01</reqdat>
        </line>
        <line>
            <lineno>2</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-03-01</reqdat>
        </line>
        <line>
            <lineno>3</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-02-01</reqdat>
        </line>
    </header>
</doc>

The result I'm looking for is the following.
<doc>
    <header>
        <ordernum>1234</ordernum>
        <customer>1</customer>
        <line>
            <lineno>2</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-03-01</reqdat>
        </line>
        <line>
            <lineno>3</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-02-01</reqdat>
        </line>
        <line>
            <lineno>1</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-01-01</reqdat>
        </line>
    </header>
</doc>

The use case is that this is being sent to a printer that uses the order in the XML and the lines need to print in this order.
I'm playing around with the sorted function and lambda sort but haven't figured it out.

Try:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """
<doc>
    <header>
        <ordernum>1234</ordernum>
        <customer>1</customer>
        <line>
            <lineno>1</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-01-01</reqdat>
        </line>
        <line>
            <lineno>2</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-03-01</reqdat>
        </line>
        <line>
            <lineno>3</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-02-01</reqdat>
        </line>
    </header>
</doc>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)


header = root.find(".//header")
lines = header.findall(".//line")
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda tag: tag.find("reqdat").text, reverse=True)

for l in header:
    if l.tag == "line":
        header.remove(l)

for l in lines:
    header.append(l)

print(ET.tostring(root, encoding="unicode"))

Prints:
<doc>
    <header>
        <ordernum>1234</ordernum>
        <customer>1</customer>
        <line>
            <lineno>2</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-03-01</reqdat>
        </line>
        <line>
            <lineno>3</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-02-01</reqdat>
        </line>
    <line>
            <lineno>1</lineno>
            <reqdat>2024-01-01</reqdat>
        </line>
        </header>
</doc>


Thanks!  I was able to get your code to work but needed to convert the header object to a list first.  So for l in list(header) worked.
